# Picasa Web Album Data API v2 : (400) Bad Request' error thrown while uploading photo with metadata

Tags: c#, picasa, google-oauth

I am trying to upload an image with metadata using Picasa Web Album Data API v2 in C# as mentioned in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#PostPhotoWithMetadata) .

The http post request is failing with **400 Bad Request** error with no details what my request is missing or where it is malformed.

Following is my code:

```
      byte[] image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("fullimagepath");
            int imglenth= image.Length;
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(image);

            string rawImgXml="<entry xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\'>"+"\n"+
                "<title>plz-to-love-realcat.png</title>"+"\n"+
                "<summary>Real cat wants attention too</summary>"+"\n"+
                "<category scheme=\"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind\"\n"+
                "term=\"http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#photo\"/>"+"\n"+
                "</entry>";

            string data = "";
             data ="\nMedia multipart posting\n"+
                "--END_OF_PART\n"+
                      "Content-Type: application/atom+xml\n\n"+
                        rawImgXml + "\n"
                +"--END_OF_PART\n"
                +"Content-Type: image/png\n"+
                           text+"\n"+
                "--END_OF_PART--";
            int length=data.Length;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/"+tc.userId+"/albumid/"+"6150508893827643953"+"?access_token="+tc.auth_Token);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentType = "multipart/related; boundary=END_OF_PART";
            request.ContentLength = length;
            request.Headers.Add("GData-Version","2");
            request.Headers.Add("MIME-Version","1.0");
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            int start = 0;
            int chunkSize = 1024 * 4; // changed form 100 to 4
            double percentage = 0;

            while (start <= bytes.Length)
            {
                if (start + chunkSize > bytes.Length)
                    requestStream.Write(bytes, start, bytes.Length - start);
                else
                    requestStream.Write(bytes, start, chunkSize);
                start += chunkSize;
            }

            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Image data is being converted to ASCII and then appended to data string. After trying many permutation and combinations from past 3 days its failing with the same error. Totally unable to figure out where the request is going wrong?

Uploading the image without metadata works perfectly but I want to upload videos too in my application which cannot be done without metadata.

Any directions or pointers will be of great help! Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here when I try to upload a photo WITH metadata, however without metadata it works fine.

Could you try this request: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#PostPhotos and let us know how it goes?